# how to find all values under a field in mongo and create a map of it?

Tags: java, mongodb, scala, mongodb-query

I have a mongo collection that looks like this:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("456391bf2db8613231935362"), "country" : "denmark", "city" : "copenhagen" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("456391bf2db8613231935363"), "country" : "denmark", "city" : "odense" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("456391bf2db8613231935364"), "country" : "austria", "city" : "vienna" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("456391bf2db8613231935365"), "country" : "austria", "city" : "vilach" }
...
```

and I want to create a find method that find me all the cities in a country as a map, started with something like:

```
def findAllCittiesPerCountry(): Future[Map[String,List[String]]] = {

  myCollection.find.map(obj => obj.get("country").get).toFuture().map(x => x.distinct)

}
```

but its not the solution, too clumsy and not clean enough...

does someone have a suggestion?

thanks!

Comment: You will have to use Mongo aggregation. Its very simple to do with Aggregation

Comment: You could have a look at http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.12/documentation/advanced-topics/aggregation.html#aggregation-framework